# Is there anyway to use a member function as a default parameter?

Tags: c++, member-functions, default-parameters

It tried something like this, which doesn't work. Is there a way to get a similar effect?

```
class A
{
public:
  int foo();
  void bar(int b = foo());
};
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Give us a real example of what you want to do.

Comment: I have a member function like such getDistance(Units units = getDefaultUnits()); so I don't have to specify the units unless i want something other than the default. I've also thought about adding DEFAULT to the Units enum.

Comment: It might be an even better idea to add different types for your different units and add implicit conversion functions between all your different units. That way, you can explicitly use units where u need them, and let the compiler take care of the rest! Remember that using types is very cheap in C++, usually free if you do it right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. Overload the function and call the member-function in it.

`void bar() { bar(foo()); }`

Comment: I'm trying to understand this. Could you help me? I'm so confused, don't see the purpose of this. You now have 2 bar()'s declared, one to just call another one?

Comment: @Nicklamort: Actually when you've default value for a parameter, then you can call that function without passing any argument for that parameter; you can optionally pass argument also. This is exactly what is the situation here. You can call *bar* as `bar()` as well as `bar(10)`... so in effect it *seems* that bar's parameter has default value!

Comment: Oooh I see, so with overloaded functions, you can, like, 'simulate' default parameters..nice. Thx for clarifying nawaz! :)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this since it's a bunch of extra code, but it does solve the problem.