# C++ : call another method for default method argument

Tags: c++, dynamic, methods, default-value, overloading

I'm playing with the default arguments for my Settings class in my project, so that I have a bit fewer methods declared.

For instance, I have these methods declared:

```
class Settings
{
    // [..]

    int getCurrentUserID(); // returns current user id

    // you specify the user id
    int setSetting( int value, int user_id ); 
    // no user specified, use the current one, overloads the previous when called
    // with only 1 argument
    int setSetting( int value ); 
}
```

What I'd like to have is this simplified version:

```
class Settings
{
    // [..]

    int getCurrentUserID(); // returns current user id

    // automatically selects the current user if no ID is provided
    int setSetting( int value, int user_id = getCurrentUserID() ); 
}
```

But I get this error at compilation:

```
cannot call member function ‘int Settings::getCurrentUserID()’ without object
```

How could I tell the compiler to use the current instance (which is available through the *this*)  of the Setting object to get the default value?
Is this authorized, by the way?

Comment: "How could I..." — you cannot. The standards says `this` cannot be used in this context, implicitly or explicitly (8.3.6/8, 8.3.6/9).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901233/is-there-anyway-to-use-a-member-function-as-a-default-parameter ?

Comment: ltjax: yep, didn't find it myself... I suspected this had to be already on SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getCurrentUserID()` is not static, so you can only call it through an object. One option is to create 2 methods, like the ones bellow, this and call the one you need:

```
int setSetting(int value);

int setSetting(int value, int user_id);
```

Another option: assuming the ID is always positive, you can give a default negative ID on the method and verify inside the method if the method was called with an ID or not. Something like this:

```
int setSetting(int value, int user_id = -1) {
    if (user_id == -1) {
        this->setSetting(value, this.getCurrentUserID());
        return 0; //don't know what the function returns, but handle it the way you need
    }

    // rest of the function will be called recursively, but it's OK
    // because the ID is not -1!
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to have `if (user_id == -1) user_id = getCurrentUserID());` as the first line and then continuing the function instead of calling itself. This would also avoid infinite recursion if getCurrentUserID() happens to be -1.

Comment: Ok, I'll take yours: it shows the reason (non-static function) and a solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have two good choices. First, assuming `-1` is not a legal `user_id`:

```
class Settings
{
    // [..]

    int getCurrentUserID(); // returns current user id

    // automatically selects the current user if no ID is provided
    int setSetting( int value, int user_id = -1); 
};

int Settings::setSetting( int value, int user_id )
{
    if(user_id == -1) user_id = getCurrentUserID();
 ...
```

Alternatively:

```
class Settings
{
    // [..]

    int getCurrentUserID(); // returns current user id

    int setSetting( int value ) { return setSetting(value, getCurrentUserID() ); }

    int setSetting( int value, int user_id ); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Only static methods can be used as a default parameter values. This example works (verified):

   ```
   class Settings
   {
       // [..]

       static int getCurrentUserID(); // returns current user id

       // automatically selects the current user if no ID is provided
       int setSetting( int value, int user_id = getCurrentUserID() ); 
   };
   ```
2. Default parameter values should be avoided in C++ not to complicate the code.
3. It's a good practise overloading methods.
   I think your 1st example seems to look better and simplier that the other one with default value.

Comment: Unfortunately, compiling is not verification in C++ because of the many implementation defined and undefined behaviours.